# Devise authentication generating bad SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I have a small inherited rails project that uses devise to authenticate.

Recently it has started making an incorrect query to the database if the user enters an invalid password, as set out below.  Previously it works as expected. I must have changed something, but I do not know what.

#### With a VALID password

When the user logs in with a VALID password, the console log shows similar to this

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 192.168.2.30 at 2015-07-13 08:13:39 -0400
Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"A_Long_Authenticity_Token_Goes_Here", "user"=>{"email"=>"m.mouse@disney.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["email", "m.mouse@disney.com"]]
  (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = $1, "current_sign_in_at" = $2, "sign_in_count" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "users"."id" = $5  [["last_sign_in_at", "2015-07-10 21:17:12.592611"], ["current_sign_in_at", "2015-07-13 12:13:39.359997"], ["sign_in_count", 1000], ["updated_at", "2015-07-13 12:13:39.363621"], ["id", 22]]
  (17.6ms)  COMMIT
```

and the system carries on as normal.

#### With an INvalid password

When the user attempts to log in with an INVALID password, the console log shows similar to this

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 192.168.2.30 at 2015-07-13 07:44:55 -0400
Processing by Users::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"A_Long_Authenticity_Token_Goes_Here", "user"=>{"email"=>"m.mouse@disney.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  User Load (53.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["email", "m.mouse@disney.com"]]
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 288ms (ActiveRecord: 53.4ms)
Processing by Users::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"A_Long_Authenticity_Token_Goes_Here", "user"=>{"email"=>"m.mouse@disney.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  User Load (2.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "email"."email" = 'm.mouse@disney.com' AND "email"."password" = 'ThisIsAnInvalidPassword' AND "email"."remember_me" = '0'  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "email"
LINE 1: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "email"."email" = 'm.mou....
: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "email"."email" = 'm.mouse@disney.com' AND "email"."password" = 'ThisIsAnInvalidPassword' AND "email"."remember_me" = '0'  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 19ms (ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)
<< Output standard rails error page >>
```

So far as I understand this, the system tries to read the `user` table as expected, but no row is found.  Devise munges this into a 401 Unauthorized response.  The system is then attempting to redirect back to the login page somehow using `Users::SessionsController#new`

The system then tries a completely new query trying to look up the user using a half formatted query. The query tries to include a table called `email` that does not exist in the database; the query syntax is not correct either.

Database: postgres

Rails: 2.1.2

Devise gem: 3.5.1 according to bundle show

There is no `Users::SessionsController#create` def, so presumably using the underlying devise version

There is a `Users::SessionsController#new` as follows

```
def new
    if (Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?) && params[:user]
        user = User.where(email: params[:user]).first
        sign_in :user, user
        redirect_to dashboard_home_path
    else
        super
    end
  end
```

The environment is `development`

Nothing appears to be being written to the `sessions` table whether the login is successful or not.

Where does that second malformed query even come from, and why does devise try to use/call `Users::SessionsController#new` after an invalid login attempt anyway?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The query is coming from your application's code, which we can't see.

Comment: Also, please confirm if you mean Ruby 2.1.2 and hopefully Rails 4 if you're using that gem version of devise.

Comment: Thanks Brian.  Sorry about that :  It's rails 4.2.1, and ruby 2.1.2